# Parsing JSON objects and storing in mysql variables

Tags: mysql, json, stored-procedures, mysql-json

I am trying to parse a json array and its objects to further make use of them in my mysql procedure.

But while reading the values it shows null.
_list  will contain

> [{"floor_id":"5","length":"40"},{"floor_id":"6","length":"61"}]

Code:

```
     CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `manage_room`(IN _id INT,
                                                        IN _list JSON,                                                    
                                                        INOUT v_message varchar(1000),
                                                        INOUT v_code int
                                                           
                                                        )
    BEGIN
    declare _floor_number int ;
declare floor_list_length int;
set floor_list_length =3;
                            iterator:
                            LOOP  
                                IF floor_list_length = 0 OR floor_list_length IS NULL THEN
                                    LEAVE iterator;
                                END IF;  
                                select JSON_EXTRACT(_rooms_list,CONCAT('$._list[', `floor_list_length`, '].floor_id')) as f ;
                                select JSON_EXTRACT(_rooms_list,CONCAT('$._list[', `floor_list_length`, '].length')) as l ;
                                insert into temp(val,txt) values (f,l);
            end loop;
    
    end
```

Can someone correct me what mistake i am doing?

Comment: Try: `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(\`_list\`, '$[0].floor_id') as f ;`.

Comment: With respect, there are so many mistakes I don't know where to begin. The input parameter is `_list` but you reference it as `_rooms_list`. Then you use `$._list` in the JSON path, but that key doesn't appear in the JSON content. You declare a variable `_floor_number` but you do not use it. Then you use a variable `floor_list_length` without declaring it or setting a value. You try to select fields from the JSON with aliases but you don't set them to any variable. Then you use `f` and `l` as if they are variables. This procedure is totally gibberish.

Comment: You edited your question to add the declaration of `_floor_number` and set it to 3. But there are still many other problems.

Comment: @BillKarwin Sorry, that was not the complete code. My thought was to give an idea what I am trying to achieve in the program. I should have given complete code :-(

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean to do is to insert multiple rows to the table `temp` corresponding to the array in your JSON input document. Each member of the JSON array has a pair of fields, and these two fields should be set to the columns `val` and `txt` in the `temp` table.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `manage_room`(
  IN _id INT,
  IN _list JSON,                                                    
  INOUT v_message varchar(1000),
  INOUT v_code int
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE floor_list_length INT;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE element JSON;

  SET floor_list_length = JSON_LENGTH(_list);

  WHILE i < floor_list_length DO
    SET element = JSON_EXTRACT(_list, CONCAT('$[',i,']'));

    INSERT INTO temp
    SET val = JSON_EXTRACT(element, '$.floor_id'),
        txt = JSON_EXTRACT(element, '$.length');

    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

But here's an even simpler solution, assuming you use MySQL 8.0. Make the JSON into a set of rows using JSON_TABLE(), then insert that set directly into the `temp` table.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `manage_room`(
  IN _id INT,
  IN _list JSON,                                                    
  INOUT v_message varchar(1000),
  INOUT v_code int
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TEMP (val, txt)
  SELECT j.floor_id, j.length FROM JSON_TABLE(
    _list, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
      floor_id INT PATH '$.floor_id',
      length INT PATH '$.length'
    )
  ) AS j;
END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to solve it using the syntax mentioned by wchiquito.
Your code have some more information on different ways to extract the values. I am fiddling with the documentation as well. Thanks for your patience :-)